# How to read data of $http request inside controller from a service?

Tags: ajax, angularjs, http, service

I'm trying to save the return value of $http service inside my controller, but I get "undefined" like response

In my controller, I call a service that uses the $http:

```
//this returns undefined
vm.user_instruments = instruments.getInstruments();
```

My service:

```
function instruments($http){
       this.getInstruments = function(){
         $http.get('url/').
          then(function(response) {
            /*this console.log print the response, 
            but this value I can't get it in my controller*/
            console.log(response.data);
            return response.data;
          }, function(error) {
            return error.data;
          });
       }
     }//end service
```

**So, what am I doing wrong?** My purpose is that the controller be ignorant of any details of HTTP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several problems . First your service function isn't returning anything .... return `$http` from it.

```
this.getInstruments = function(){
   // return the request promise
   return  $http.get('url/').
      then(function(response) {            
        return response.data;
      }, function(error) {
        return error.data;
      });
   }
```

Then in controller assign the scope inside a promise callback:

```
instruments.getInstruments().then(function(data){
  vm.user_instruments = data
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you have two options to do this:

#### 1. return the promise to the controller and use the promise in the controller

```
function service ($http) {
    this.request = function () {
        return $http.request({ /*...*/ });
    };
}

function controller (service) {
    service.request().then(function (resp) {
        console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

#### 2. send callback to service and return the data to the callback

```
function service ($http) {
    this.request = function (callback) {
        return $http.request({ /*...*/ }).then(function (resp) {
            callback(null, resp);
        }, function (err) {
            callback(err);
        });
    };
}

function controller (service) {
    service.request(function (err, resp) {
        if (err) return console.log(err);

        console.log(resp);
    });
}
```

### the popular option is to use promises, so use option 1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

Service:

```
function instruments($http){
  this.get = function(callback){ 
       $http.get('/url').success(function(res){
            callback(res);
       });
    }
 } /* end service */
```

Controller:

```
instruments.get(function(res){
     vm.instruments = res;
});
```

It should work.
PS: typed in mobile.

Comment: Note that `success` is being deprecated in favor of promise api per `$http` docs

Comment: Depends what version he is using.

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah got it mate :)